# dimension of an intersection of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be the vector space of all polynomials in one variable with real coefficients having degree at most 20. Define the subspaces 
\begin{align*}
    W_1 &=\{p \in V; p(1)=0,p(1/2)=0, p(5)=0,p(7)=0\} \\
    W_2 &=\{p \in V; p(3)=0,p(1/2)=0, p(4)=0,p(7)=0\}
\end{align*}
then the dimension of $W_1 \cap W_2$

Comment: is the dimension 15?

Comment: Can you please add the work that you've done on the question?  If this is homework, please read [How to ask a homework question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/23353) on meta

Comment: w1 intersection W2= {p belongs to V; p(1)=0,p(1/2)=0, p(5)=0,p(7)=0,p(3)=0,p(4)=0}. and dim V =21.

Comment: I reformatted what you typed but the question is still incomplete.  Please fill it in with your question (and your work).  Also, I made the title something more descriptive than just the first $N$ characters of the question; feel free to change it to something better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your intuition is correct: $\dim(W_1 \cap W_2) =15$.

One way to see this is to set up a linear mapping $T\colon V \to \mathbb{R}^6$, 
$$
T(p) = \begin{bmatrix} p(1) \\ p(1/2) \\ p (5) \\ p(7) \\ p(3) \\ p(4) \end{bmatrix}
$$
Then $T$ is surjective and $W_1 \cap W_2 = \ker T$.  By the rank-nullity theorem,
$$
\dim(\ker T) + \dim(\operatorname{im}T) = \dim V
$$
Since $\dim V = 21$ and $\dim(\operatorname{im}T) = \dim \mathbb{R}^6 = 6$, we have
$$
\dim(W_1 \cap W_2) = \dim(\ker T) = 21 - 6 = 15
$$

Comment: How to prove that T is onto?

Comment: @user114873: Since $T$ is linear, it suffices to show all the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^6$ are in the image.  And for that you can construct polynomials $p \in V$ which are one at exactly one of the values $a=1$, $a=1/2$, $a=5$, $a=7$, $a=3$, $a=4$, and zero at the the rest.

Comment: Very Elegant. Thanks